# Some time music does not stop android

Tags: android

There is an function which is called on onCreate method of playing music...

```
    public void playBeep() {
    try {

        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("beep.mp3");
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.setLooping(true);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

and on onPause method i have written code of stop music so when user leaves activity music should automatically stops...

```
        @Override
protected void onPause() {
    isBeeping = false;
    if (m != null) {

        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

but sometime it is working fine but sometime music does not stop!!!

can anybody suggest me how to stop music when leaving activity :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    isBeeping = false;
    if (m != null)
       m.release();       
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pratik first i have used function like this but sometime illegalStateException is thrown that's why i have put condition isPlaying

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit okay then with that condition but dont call `m.stop();` in that just call `m.release();` directly.